# SQL Update help

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, oracle

I have a really simple question, is it possible to update a table with new values using just one update statement.

Say for example I have a table with author, title, date, popularity. Now I got some new data which has author name, title corresponding new popularity. How do I update the table now in one statement. Note that author and title are not unique.

Comment: Do you mean "insert the value if it's not there or update if it is there"? Or do you only want to update existing records? If so, @icktoofay has the answer.

Comment: if no value is there.. then we need to insert it, if it is there.. then update it.

Comment: ~ What SQL platform? T-SQL (Microsoft's), MySQL, Oracle, NoSQL, etc...

Comment: yeah.. sorry i missed the details. I am using Rails with a Oracle database..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it in a single statement using Oracle's MERGE statement:

```
MERGE DestinationTable target
USING   (
        Select 'Briggs' Author, 'My Next Master' Title, 6 Popularity
        Union All Select 'Millis', 'Man up, Nut head', 3
        ) Z
        ON Z.Author = target.Author
            And Z.Title = target.Title
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET target.Popularity = Z.Popularity
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    Insert(Author, Title, Popularity) Values(Z.Author, Z.Title, Z.Popularity);
```

[Oracle's MERGE statement](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/statements_9016.htm#sthref6538)

Comment: Pretty cool. Thanks. Just for the sake of knowing, is there anything similar in other SQL platforms?
@sameera mentioned `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` which is also kinda cool. Specifically is there anything for sqlite?

Comment: @Cyborgo - Yes. SQL Server 2008 supports pretty much the same MERGE syntax.

Comment: @Cyborgo - AFAIK, SQLIte does not support MERGE.

Comment: ~ I was about to ask the same question, thanks for the info re: MERGE for SQL Server 2k8. New tool in my bag!

Answer (score 1):

Since I posted a comment, I'll post an answer as well. @icktoofay posted one solution, but using [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/miah/sql-if-exists-update-else-insert) we can follow that it's actually going to cause a table scan, so instead try Jeremiah Clark's solution of:

```
UPDATE Table1 SET (...) WHERE Column1='SomeValue'
IF @@ROWCOUNT=0
    INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (...)
```

Note that this tries to update first, and if it succeeds, `@@ROWCOUNT` will be 1 or more, but I'm making the assumption you'll be using T-SQL (Microsoft's SQL language). I don't know that `@@ROWCOUNT` is supported by any other platforms.

Comment: hey. i couldn't write the comment properly, so I wrote it as an answer.. could you please look into it and let me know if it is possible or not. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, something like this should work:

```
update books set popularity=? where author=? and title=?
```

...where `?` is a placeholder.

**Edit:** According to your comment, you want to create it if it doesn't exist and update it if it does. I don't think you can do that with one statement, but I might be wrong. In two statements, you could use this to check if it exists already:

```
select count(*) from books where author=? and title=? limit 1
```

That would output 1 if it exists or 0 if it doesn't. From there you can choose whether to insert or update.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this in SQL Anywhere (not sure what DBMS you're using, though)

```
INSERT INTO "books" ("title", "author", "popularity") ON EXISTING UPDATE VALUES(?,?,?);
```

So if the record exists, it simply updates it.  Otherwise, create a new record.

Comment: I think we need to know his platform too... I'll add another comment on the question

Comment: Yeah, and I'm not sure off the top of my head if the 'ON EXISTING UPDATE' is a vendor extension or not.

Answer (score 0):

In mySQL you have a command called something called 'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE' and I found the same for oracle (its called Merge)

take a look at this article

http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/2009/05/25/mysql-merge-gone-awry/

cheers,
sameera